# cannot access AJAX input parameter in Action class

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

JSP/JQuery call:-

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ApplyCouponCode",
  type: "POST",
  data: {couponCode: $('#PaymentMethod_couponCode').val()},
  dataType: "json",
  error: function(){
      alert('Error');
  },
  success: function(data){   
   alert('SUCCESS');
   $('#spanValidatedCoupon').text('Is coupon valid? ' + data.couponIsValid + ' couponAmount = ' + data.couponAmount);
  }
```

});

Action Class:

```
 public String applyCouponCode() throws Exception {
    if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
        logger.debug("data: couponCode '" + couponCode + "'");    
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

The Action class method [applyCouponCode] is invoked. But couponCode is null.. please advise. couponCode has public getter/setter methods .. what else do i need to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your action method should take couponCode as a parameter. Assuming couponCode is type string, your action method should look something like this:

```
public String ApplyCouponCode(string couponCode)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Struts2 action methods don't take parameters.

Comment: I found the error: data: {couponCode: $('#PaymentMethod_couponCode').val()},

should have been 

data: {couponCode: $('#PaymentMethod_CouponCode').val()}, .. i.e. with uppercase C in CouponCode.

Thank you for your responses. sorry to bother you with something this silly.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you go directly at ApplyCouponCode?couponCode=your_coupon_code